# First inaccessible Suslin trees in L, an interesting detail

Tags: lo.logic, large-cardinals, posets, trees

It's known (but quite nontrivial) that $V=L$ implies that if $\kappa$ is the 1st inaccessible cardinal then there are $\kappa$-Suslin trees $T$.

Such a tree $T$ can be considered as a forcing notion in $L$.
Being Suslin, $T$ does not collapse $\kappa$.

QUESTION. Can such $T$ be defined so that the $T$-forcing over $L$ preserves all smaller cardinals?

Answer (score 9):

This will always be true. That is, I claim that forcing with a $\kappa$-Suslin tree always preserves all smaller cardinals, and indeed, preserves all cardinals and cofinalities.

**Theorem.** Forcing with a $\kappa$-Suslin tree preserves all cardinals and cofinalities.

**Proof.** Suppose $G$ is $V$-generic for a $\kappa$-Suslin tree $T$, where $\kappa$ is regular. Note that $\kappa$ is preserved, and all cardinals and cofinalities above $\kappa$, since the forcing is $\kappa$-c.c. Meanwhile, the filter $G$ is determined by a branch through $T$, and this branch is $\kappa$-closed in $V[G]$. This is enough to see that the forcing will be ${<}\kappa$-distributive, as follows. If $\sigma$ is a name for a $\beta$-sequence over $V$, for some $\beta<\kappa$, then the value of every entry $\sigma(\check\alpha)$ is determined by some condition on the generic branch. Since $\kappa$ remains regular in the extension, these conditions will be bounded on the branch, and so there will be some piece of the branch, a condition in the forcing, that decides all the values $\sigma(\check\alpha)$ for $\alpha<\beta$. So this condition forces that $\sigma$ is equal to a $\beta$-sequence from the ground model. So the forcing adds no new ${<}\kappa$-sequences over the ground model, and hence preserves all cardinals and cofinalities below $\kappa$. $\Box$

The argument works more generally to show that whenever one is forcing with a normal tree of height $\kappa$, and $\kappa$ remains regular in the extension, then the forcing will add no new ${<}\kappa$-sequences.

Comment: Yes thank  you. And I suppose the argument can be condensed in a forcing-free proof by choosing a maximal antichain in each dense set (in a given $<\kappa$-size family of dense sets).

Comment: Yes, indeed. So there will be a level of the tree deciding any given name for a new $\beta$-sequence. In other words, any fewer than $\kappa$ many maximal antichains is refined by a single maximal antichain.

Comment: Joel by some reasons I want to study this construction of a $\kappa$-ST in $L$, for $\kappa$ being the 1st inaccessible, in detail, but w|o going into the full course of the fine structure. Can you recommend anything better than Devlin-Constructibility? Unfortunately neither Jech nor Kunen books contain this construction.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know it myself.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei  There is a detailed combinatorial construction of a κ-Souslin tree in section 2 of [A microscopic approach to Souslin-tree construction, Part II](http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/23), where the construction is uniform and therefore applies regardless of whether κ is a successor or inaccessible.  In particular, a combinatorial principle that holds in L for every regular uncountable cardinal  is defined in subsection 2.6, and the construction from that principle is given in subsection 2.7.

Comment: Correction:  The principle holds in L for **every regular uncountable cardinal that is not weakly compact**.  But of course that still includes the first inaccessible, which is what you were asking for.

Comment: @Ari Brodsky thank you, I have downloaded the arxiv version, hopefully it's what I need to go ahead with.